# Implementing a scheduler for a thread library

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, operating-system, ucontext

I am implementing a thread library in C using *makecontext()*, *getcontext()* and *swapcontext()*. I need to implement a scheduler which is invoked every 5 ms in order to switch contexts with another thread (round robin). How could I implement this timer functionality? If I put the timer in the scheduler, then it will be impossible for time to be incremented while the scheduler is not running. Is there a way to associate a timer with a particular process that updates no matter what context is active?

Comment: The timer could just run in its own thread with a callback being invoked every 5ms. Even if it were running inside the scheduler thread, you could still invoke the callback.

Comment: the issue is that even if the scheduler or timer thread is not running, I still need the time to be updating. For example, if a particular thread is running that is not the scheduler or timer thread, how could I keep track of the amount of time? @Nina

Comment: So I assume you have a deadlock loop in your timer thread that waits 5ms then does a context switch? If that's the case, you could use asynchronious timers instead in which you would not need to handle the time increment yourself.

Comment: A hardware timer interrupt is traditionally used.

Answer (score 0):

A solution based on *[setitimer()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setitimer.2.html)* system call could do the job. This can be programmed to trigger a cyclic **SIGALRM** signal. It could then be possible to attach a signal handler which would trigger the scheduler.